# Is there any memory leak for the implementation of array of char arrays

Tags: c

Basically, I declared a char array to hold a maximum size of 100 char arrays.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add_to_urls(char **urls, char *url) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (urls[i] == NULL) {
            urls[i] = malloc(sizeof(strlen(url) + 1));
            strcpy(urls[i], url);
            break;
        } else {
            //make sure we don't add same site twice
            if (strcmp(urls[i], url) == 0) {
                printf("%s already in list\n", urls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void free_urls(char **urls) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (urls[i] != NULL) {
            free(urls[i]);
        } else break;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *urls[100] = {NULL};

    char *url = "www.youtube.com";
    add_to_urls(urls, url);

    url = "www.reddit.com";
    add_to_urls(urls, url);

    url = "www.reddit.com";
    add_to_urls(urls, url);

    printf("URL: %s\n", urls[0]);
    printf("URL: %s\n", urls[1]);

    free_urls(urls);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if there's any conventions of making such an array container, as I am learning how to use `c`. The **priority** is to check if there's any memory leak, what I did is iteratively release the `urls[i]` and urls itself will be automatically handled (I suspect).

The second thing is about improvements, what do you think might be inappropriate causing any potential troubles?

Comment: If you want to check for memory errors then I'd recommend installing [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and running your program through it

Comment: Code with bugs in it is specifically off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error here:

```
        urls[i] = malloc(sizeof(strlen(url) + 1));
```

`strlen(url) + 1` is of type `size_t`, so you will allocate enough space for that, which could well be less than the amount you actually wanted (`strlen(url) + 1`).

If we fix that bug, and also change `url` to `const char*` (because it points at string literals, which are always const), then we get a clean Valgrind run from the test program.

---

What does the return value from `add_to_urls` indicate?  If you meant it to be true when the url was added, then the `break` should be replaced with `return 1`.

Always check the result of `malloc()` is not null.

Errors and warnings should be printed to the standard error stream, not to `stdout`.

Your `main()` doesn't check that we didn't add a duplicate.  In fact we did, but we never printed it.

Avoid writing constants (such as `100`) in separate places if they need to agree with each other.

Instead of the `break` in `free_urls()`, we can make the test part of the loop's condition.

---

## Improved code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int add_to_urls(char **urls, const char *url, size_t max_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < max_list;  i++) {
        if (!urls[i]) {
            urls[i] = malloc(strlen(url) + 1);
            if (!urls[i]) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to alloc for %s\n", url);
                return 0; /* failed allocation */
            }
            strcpy(urls[i], url);
            return 1;           /* we added it */
        }
        //make sure we don't add same site twice
        if (strcmp(urls[i], url) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s already in list\n", url);
            return 0;           /* already present */
        }
    }
    return 0; /* ran out of room */
}

void free_urls(char **urls, size_t max_list) {
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < max_list && urls[i];  i++) {
        free(urls[i]);
    }
}
    
int main() {
    char *urls[100] = {NULL};
    const size_t url_len = sizeof urls / sizeof *urls;

    add_to_urls(urls, "www.youtube.com", url_len);
    add_to_urls(urls, "www.reddit.com", url_len);
    add_to_urls(urls, "www.reddit.com", url_len);

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < url_len && urls[i];  i++) {
        printf("URL[%zd]: %s\n", i, urls[i]);
    }

    free_urls(urls, url_len);
}
```